# Zeroes of an analytic function lie inside a disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Given any $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an $n$ sufficiently large such that the function
$$ f_{n}(z)=1+\frac{1}{2!z^{2}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n!z^{n}}$$
Has all it's zeroes inside the circle $|z|<\varepsilon$.

Here's what I have so far. Note that $f_{n}(z) \to e^{\frac{1}{z}}$ as $n \to \infty$ meaning that given any $\varepsilon>0$ we have $|f_{n}(z)-e^{\frac{1}{z}}|<\varepsilon$. Suppose we have a zero $w$ for $f_{n}$. Plugging this in gives us $$|e^{\frac{1}{w}}|< \varepsilon$$.  But wouldn't this imply that $w$ is large and therefor not particularly close to zero?

Comment: $f_n(1/z)$ converges locally uniformly to $e^{z}$ that is for any $r,\delta$ there is $N_{r,\delta}$ such that $|f_n(1/z)-e^{z}| \le \delta$ for $n \ge N_{\epsilon,\delta}, |z| \le r$. With $\delta = \frac12 \inf_{|z| \le r} |e^z|$ then ... If you don't know that it converges to $e^z$ then you need to show the limit doesn't vanish looking at $f_n(1/(a+b))-f_n(1/a)f_n(1/b)\to 0$ or $\frac{-z^2 f_n'(z)}{f_n(z)}\to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we need $|\mathcal{R}(e^{\frac{1}{w}})| < \epsilon$ as the imaginary part is always modulus $1$.

What does this tell us?

Write $w = x+iy$,

$|\mathcal{R}(e^{\frac{1}{w}})| < \epsilon \iff |e^{\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}}|<\epsilon$. We need the power of $e$ to be a very large negative number. This is only possible if $x$ is small and negative, and $y$ is small too.